# Java, converter valor Hexadecimal de ponto flutuante

Tags: java, conversão, hexadecimal

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que recebe dados de uma placa GPS, os dados são recebidos por bluetooth em hexadecimal, os valores de latitude e longitude são pontos flutuantes de 64 bits, que segue a norma IEEE 754.

Eu já consigo capturar os valores em hexadecimal de que preciso para uma variável String. Por exemplo:

> b3baf6e3530b38c0 (latitude)
>
> ff198e4d752f4ac0 (longitude)

Mas não estou conseguindo transformar esta String com o valor hexadecimal nos valores da latitude e longitude, como por exemplo: -24.123456789 e -52.123456789.

Alguém conheçe alguma maneira de interpretar o valor hexadecimal de um ponto flutuante, para uma variável double?

Comment: Só par confirmar, para os dois valores do seu exemplo os doubles desejados seriam respectivamente `-1.677999117094125E-59` e `-1.7525333784680737E304`?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Não sei de onde o Romão tirou esses números hexadecimais, mas os dois números em decimal que você sugeriu devem estar errados, a julgar pelos expoentes.

Comment: Pois é, até conferi contra [uma calculadora](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=B3BAF6E3530B38C0). Talvez os bits estejam invertidos de alguma forma? :)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Sim, também estou tentando fazer alguns testes matemáticos para ver se isso pode de alguma forma produzir um número factível. O fato de ambos terminarem com `c0` me faz suspeitar sobre algum reordenamento.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly A norma IEEE 754 defini o hexa retornado, pelo que vi em: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754, o hexa é composto de: Sinal, expoente e mantissa.

Comment: Então, peço desculpas mas encontrei a resposta de porque não consigo converter. Estou recebendo os valores espelhados, então se inverter a sequencia de hexadecimal e tentar converter normalmente ele retorna os valores corretos. b3baf6e3530b38c0 na verdade é c0380b53e3f6bab3

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é que os valores recebidos da placa que transmite o GPS estão vindo de forma espelhada, por isso não estava conseguindo obter os valores reais.
então o valor b3baf6e3530b38c0 na verdade é c0380b53e3f6bab3
Para realizar a conversão, eu utilizei o seguinte código:

```
public double hexToDouble(String hexvalue){
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(new BigInteger(hexvalue,16).longValue());
}
```